# Erro ao tentar pegar o valor em uma seção da XML, em VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

O erro acontece logo quando ele passa no primeiro elemento "dEmi".

XML:

```
<ide>
  <cUF>11</cUF>
  <cNF>855305</cNF>
  <mod>59</mod>
  <nserieSAT>900000980</nserieSAT>
  <nCFe>000225</nCFe>
  <dEmi>20150109</dEmi>
  <hEmi>132824</hEmi>
  <cDV>1</cDV>
  <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
  <CNPJ>12345678901234</CNPJ>
  <signAC>SGR-SAT SISTEMA DE GESTAO E RETAGUARDA DO SAT</signAC>
  <assinaturaQRCODE>12312</assinaturaQRCODE>
  <numeroCaixa>010</numeroCaixa>
</ide>
```

Código:

```
  Dim document = XDocument.Load("C:\MinhaXML.xml") 

        For Each rXML In document.Descendants("ide")
            sData = rXML.Elements("dEmi").value.ToString
            sHora = rXML.Elements("hEmi").Value
            sQRCODE = rXML.Elements("assinaturaQRCODE").Value
        Next
```

ERRO:

```
public member 'value' on type '<GetElements>d__11' not  found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Copilador estava entendo que "document" erá apenas um objeto porém estava dando erro no `.value`, para resolver fiz o seguinte

```
 Dim document as XDocument = XDocument.Load("C:\MinhaXML.xml")
```

Assim minha Váriavel "document" foi atribuída com a Classe `XDocument`